# Facebook Connect login-button doesn't appear when logged into Facebook

Tags: authentication, facebook, facebook-authentication

I'm using Facebook Connect's login-button on my website:

```
<fb:login-button length="long" background="light" perms="email" size="medium" onlogin="loginWithFacebookConnect()"></fb:login-button>
```

Problem is that the login button only appears when the visitor is logged out of Facebook!  That's clearly a major problem because many visitors are logged into Facebook when they visit my site...  what am I doing wrong?

***UPDATE***: Looks like Facebook slightly changed how to implement a Facebook Connect login button.  Now text within the tags is required, otherwise the button won't appear if logged into Facebook.  Strange issue and I have to imagine this affects a **ton** of websites.  I'm still verifying this, but looks like the issue is solved.  If anyone has any extra insight into this, would love to hear it.

Comment: Um, I think it's "by design".  Why would you need a login button if you're already logged in? :p

Comment: you're logged into Facebook, but not logged into my site..  I want a facebook login button for my site.  Was that not clear?

Comment: Hello, did you solve that issue ? Can you tell a bit more about it ?

Comment: @user229688, I posted my answer

Answer (score 1):

The `<fb:login-button>` element simply needs text within it.

Comment: I got that part, and will happily vote for your answer as it seems to solve my issue. What I wanted to know more about, is where did you find out (didn't see it in the docs), and also the result of the verifications you mentioned.

Comment: I did verify through many browsers and computers that this fully solved the issue of the login button sometimes not appearing when logged out.  I forget where I saw this documented, maybe I just saw it in an example somewhere.